# In Jasmine, can the describe section correspond to a method, or does it typically correspond to a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

In Jasmine, can the `describe` section correspond to a method, or does it typically correspond to a constructor function?

Comment: Imo `describe` correspond to a feature you want to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no set rule or requirement for a `describe`. You can have as many nested `describe` functions as you want so they can be as vague as `describe("myAngularController")` or as specific as `decribe("myMethod")` with `it` functions testing different inputs into the method for example. It all depends on how you want to organize your test.

Answer (score 0):

If you organized your code in [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) modules, then `describe` could be used to define a test suite which exercises a particular module. Similarly, if you have an [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) module, you would create a test suite just for that module. In case you find that your test suite includes a lot of specs (`it('should ..', function(){})`), you may consider to break your module into separate modules, test each one individually and mock the behavior of the rest using some mocking facility i.e. jasmine spies.